# disable the length password in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase (Authentication) to create account with email and password  .
when user password less 6 characters I get this message :

> the given password is invalid ( password should be at least 6 characters )

how can I disable the length of password .

Comment: From a security standpoint this should not be bypassed.

Comment: I need that because it not important in my app . thnx